# Is there any observable difference between printf(str) and fwrite(str, 1, strlen(str), stdout)?

Tags: c, printf, language-lawyer, compiler-optimization

When printing static, format-less strings, one of the common optimizations that C compilers perform is to transform calls like `printf("foobar\n");` to the equivalent `puts("foobar");`. This is valid as long as the return value is not used (C specifies that `printf` returns the number of characters written on success, but that `puts` only returns a non-negative value on success). C compilers will also transform calls like `fprintf(stdout, "foobar")` to `fwrite("foobar", 1, 6, stdout)`.

However, the `printf` to `puts` optimization only applies if the string ends with a newline, since `puts` automatically appends a newline. When it does not, I would expect that `printf` could be optimized to an equivalent `fwrite`, just like the `fprintf` case - but it seems like compilers don't do this. For example, the following code ([Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/zrbGcjnav)):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("test1\n");
    printf("test2");
    fprintf(stdout, "test3");
}
```

gets optimized to the following sequence of calls in assembly:

```c
puts("test1");
printf("test2");
fwrite("test3", 1, 5, stdout);
```

My question is: why do compilers not optimize `printf` to `fwrite` or similar in the absence of a terminating newline? Is this simply a missed optimization, or is there a semantic difference between `printf` and `fwrite` when used with static, format-less strings? If relevant, I am looking for answers that would apply to C11 or any newer standard.

Comment: "why do compilers not optimize ..." is more like "why did a few (1 or 2) compilers I tested not optimize ....".

Comment: I see no reason for `fprintf(stdout, "test3");` as `fwrite("test3", 1, 5, stdout);` vs. `printf("test3");` other than to _use_ `stdout` in the former.

Comment: Just a guess, but I suspect this area of compiler optimization hasn't been revisited in many many years. I seem to recall (incorrectly) gcc making a `fputs()` optimization on literals without `'\n'`. But after testing from gcc 7 - 11, no such optimization is made. The assembler optimization of `printf` -> `puts`, etc.. appears to be a base compiler choice, unaffected by `-Ox` optimization level choice.

Comment: ISTR that write bypasses the buffering done by puts and printf

Comment: @stark: POSIX `write` does, but standard C `fwrite` does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a missed optimization—there's no reason why a compiler *could not* do the transform you imagine—but it's a motivated one. It is significantly easier for a compiler to convert a call to `printf` into a call to `puts` than a call to `fputs` or `fwrite`, because the latter two would require the compiler to supply `stdout` as an argument.  `stdout` is a macro, and by the time the compiler gets around to doing library-call optimizations, macro definitions may no longer be available (even if the preprocessor is integrated) or it may not be possible to parse token sequences into AST fragments anymore.

In contrast, the compiler can easily turn `fprintf` into `fputs`, because it can use whatever was supplied as the  `FILE*` argument to `fprintf` to call `fputs` with as well. But I would not be surprised by a compiler that could turn `fprintf(stdout, "blah\n")` into `fputs("blah\n", stdout)` but *not* into `puts("blah")` ... because it has no way of knowing that the first argument to this `fprintf` call *is* stdout. (Keep in mind that this optimization pass is working with the IR equivalent of `&_iob[1]` or some such.)